# Whois ip in python

Tags: python, whois

Is it possible to distinguish between individual people and company/business ip ?

I mean , if you query my ip , Does a attribute exist in 'whois' for private people or I have to read the NAME field and compare it against a list of keywords. For example :

```
whois 82.xx.xxx.x
'name': 'IT-NGI-20041119' <- this is a private citizen

whois 142.251.116.171
'name': 'GOOGLE',  <-  multinational company

keyowords_list = ['GOOGLE','AMAZON']
if result in keyowords_list:
        print("business")
else:
        print("private citizen")
```

Comment: Even if you are implementing it in code, this is rarely a programming question.

Comment: There's no data associated with an IP that differentiates between personal and commercial. The example you use is basically probabilistic guessing. For example, 'IT-NGI-20041119' is likely owned by a company and is temporarily assigned to a customer. Whether it is commercial or personal is a matter of interpretation.